# How to get row id and pass to checkbox in same row but different column in react js?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-table

sample react table will look like this

```
| show            | name  |
---------------------------
| *checkbox here* | test1 |
-------------------------
```

and the code for the setting of the columns is like this

```
const columns = [{
{title: 'Show', dataIndex: 'show',
render: value => {
   let isCheck = (value == 'true');
   return <Checkbox checked={isCheck} onChange={updateShow(*row id here*)}></Checkbox>
   }
},
{title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name'}
}];
```

and the table code is like this

```
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={*data from backend*}></Table>
```

I cant seem to get the row id since the data showing in the value is the data of that column and not the primary id of that row. Need some help im still a newbie with react.

Comment: Where is the `Table` component coming from? From a quick glance at the documentation, `react-table` only seems to expose hooks

Comment: hi @jeffkmeng I use antd for my ui thats why the tag is <Table

Comment: And what do you mean by row id? The index of the row? Is the ID passed in the data from your backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ant design then render method gives you an access to 3 parameters, not only value selected with `dataIndex`

```
render: (value, row, index) => { ... }
```

Row should have all the data for a given entry, so probably it would be

```
render: (value, row) => {
   let isCheck = (value == 'true');
   return <Checkbox checked={isCheck} onChange={updateShow(row.id, isCheck)}></Checkbox>
   }
},
```

Comment: this one worked for me thankyouuu, but when I tried to pass the id to my function which is updateShow(), it displayed all the modals showing all the ids. Is it because my columns were set in an array thats why it rendered a lot of modals?

Comment: Could you provide an example with this code in codesandbox.io, or add `updateShow` code in your original question? Without this it's hard to tell anything

Comment: I was able to solve it. from 
"onChange={updateShow(row.id, isCheck)}"  -> calls function upon render
to 
"onChange={() => updateShow(row.id, isCheck)}" -> calls function only when clicked